# Return Entity Framework result as JSON

Tags: c#, json, linq, wcf-data-services

I want to get my linq query result back as json format. I have been searching for hours.

Here is my code :

```
public IEnumerable<callersW> GetAllCallersF()
{
  testCDREntities1 context = this.CurrentDataSource;
  var query = (
    from oneCaller in CurrentDataSource.TestTables
    select new
    {
      Created = oneCaller.Created,
      Answered = oneCaller.Answered,
      Destroyed = oneCaller.Destroyed,
      CallerID = oneCaller.CallerId,
      CalledID = oneCaller.CalledId,
      DisconnectionCode = oneCaller.DisconnectionCode,
      RTP_Caller_G107MOS = oneCaller.RTP_Caller_G107MOS,
      RTP_Caller_LostPackets = oneCaller.RTP_Caller_LostPackets,
      RTP_Caller_MaxRfc3550Jitter = oneCaller.RTP_Caller_MaxRfc3550Jitter,
      RTP_Caller_MeanRfc3550Jitter = oneCaller.RTP_Caller_MeanRfc3550Jitter,
      RTP_Called_G107MOS = oneCaller.RTP_Called_G107MOS,
      RTP_Called_LostPackets = oneCaller.RTP_Called_LostPackets,
      RTP_Called_MaxRfc3550Jitter = oneCaller.RTP_Called_MaxRfc3550Jitter,
      RTP_Called_MeanRfc3550Jitter = oneCaller.RTP_Called_MeanRfc3550Jitter,
    }).ToList()
    .Select(x => new callersW
    {
      Created = Convert.ToDateTime(x.Created),
      Answered = Convert.ToDateTime(x.Answered),
      Destroyed = Convert.ToDateTime(x.Destroyed),
      CallerID = x.CallerID,
      CalledID = x.CalledID,
      DisconnectionCode = Convert.ToInt32(x.DisconnectionCode),
      RTP_Caller_G107MOS = Convert.ToDouble(x.RTP_Caller_G107MOS),
      RTP_Caller_LostPackets = Convert.ToDouble(x.RTP_Caller_LostPackets),
      RTP_Caller_MaxRfc3550Jitter = Convert.ToDouble(x.RTP_Caller_MaxRfc3550Jitter),
      RTP_Caller_MeanRfc3550Jitter = Convert.ToDouble(x.RTP_Caller_MeanRfc3550Jitter),
      RTP_Called_G107MOS = Convert.ToDouble(x.RTP_Called_G107MOS),
      RTP_Called_LostPackets = Convert.ToDouble(x.RTP_Called_LostPackets),
      RTP_Called_MaxRfc3550Jitter = Convert.ToDouble(x.RTP_Called_MaxRfc3550Jitter),
      RTP_Called_MeanRfc3550Jitter = Convert.ToDouble(x.RTP_Called_MeanRfc3550Jitter)
    }).ToList();

  return  query;
}
```

Can somebody help me with this ?

Comment: 20 seconds googling: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5701077/861716

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to your project [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and serialize object eg:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);
```

More examples [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm).